# Unclear on 2D Matrix Transposal Method

Tags: algorithm, matrix

How would one go about transposing a 2D matrix in this following manner?:

I understand that there is some sort of pattern to doing this but hard-coding is not the way, so if someone can provide some advice that would be great.

Original:

4  5  2  0

7  2  1  4

9  4  2  0

7  8  9  3

into

Transpose:

3  0  4  0

9  2  1  2

8  4  2  5

7  9  7  4

Comment: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-transpose-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    for(j=1; j<=n-i; j++) {
        aux = a[i][j];
        a[i][j] = a[n-j+1][n-i+1];
        a[n-j+1][n-i+1] = aux;
    }

}
```

By looking at the matrix you can see that line i is swapped with column n-i+1, which is equivalent to the symmetrical elements relative to the second diagonal being swapped.